# REST API Status Code for user not exist

Tags: node.js, api

Status code for object not found.

I'm making GET users/57 REST API call and this user(id=57) doesn't exist. 
Shall I use 404 Status or what can be the status code used for this

Answer (score 5):

I would use error code 401 for unknown user, and not 404. 404 means the resource (IE the API endpoint) was not found.

401: Either you need to provide authentication credentials, or the credentials provided aren't valid.

Comment: your point is valid, but the OP endpoint is `users/57`, so 404 would be appropriate for the OP.. if userid was not part of the endpoint then 401 might be used..

Comment: Seems to me OP is fetching information about user with ID 57, whether that user exists or not it is not an authentication problem

Answer (score 4):

As your question is written ("GET users/57") and that user doesn't exist then **YES, the correct response is 404.**

You seem to be modeling a REST API and "user" is just another resource.
This is unrelated to authentication you are just making a GET on a domain and the resource doesn't exist, so 404 is the right answer.

Even if this is part of an authentication process (getting userdetails) the correct answer for THAT request is 404 that will be transformed in 401 at some point by security interceptor (e.g. throwing UsernameNotFoundException that extends AuthenticationException as a consequence of that 404)

Answer (score -2):

The 404 status code, or a Not Found error, means that the user is able to communicate with the server but it is unable to locate the requested file **or resource**.

This [page of REST error codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) and reasons to use them may help you in future.

Comment: Thanks @gbjbaanb 
I'm aware of the status codes
can you please tell me what can be the response status code for my scenario

Comment: @BabuBalakrishnan I think my answer was quite clear.

Comment: It wasn't quite clear. You explained what 404 status code meant but provided no alternative which was the question.